# Programming : Aufbau principle

Tags: python

I am trying to produce a function establishing the electronic configuration of an element depending of it's atomic number

```
def Klechkowski(Z):
    L=[]
    while Z!=0:
          if Z-2<=0:
             if Z-1==0:
                L.append("1s^1")
             else:
                  L.append("1s^2")
          if Z-4<=0:
             if Z-3==0:
                 L.append("2s^1")
             else:
                 L.append("2s^2")
          if Z-10<=0:
             if Z-6==4:
                 L.append("2s^1")
             else:
                   L.append("2s^2")
             ...
      
    L2=(reversed(L))
```

the result should look like: 17 --> 1s^2 2s^2 2p^6 3s^2 3p^5

i cannot figure out the way of transforming my result and which process should i repeat for each layer

Comment: At what point does `Z` change?

Comment: @Elazar consider that the last line within the loop is Z += -1

Comment: the user chooses Z at the beginning it is the atomic number

Comment: How does `L` look after the loop? How would you like it to look?

Comment: I guess you're asking for `return ' '.join(L)`

Comment: yes @Elazar to give the answer type as shown in my example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of the input, there is a fixed ordering in which you want to fill the orbitals: 1s, 2s, 2p, 3s, 3p, .... Just subtract the size of the orbital from the argument until you reach zero. Something like:

```
def klechkowski(n):
    orbitals = [("1s", 2), ("2s", 2), ("2p", 6), ("3s", 2), ...]
    output = []
    for orbital, size in orbitals:
        k = min(size, n)
        output.append("%s^%d" % (orbital, k))
        n -= k
        if n <= 0:
            break
    return " ".join(output)
```

Comment: (Nit: I'd `assert n >= 0` and check for `n == 0`)

Comment: @chepner This answer makes no sense, it is not any close to what https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufbau_principle is about.

Comment: True, although I don't think I'd distinguish between `n < 0` and `n == 0`.

Comment: @GSazheniuk I'm just not bothering compute the orbital order on the fly (which, to be fair, may be the point of the assignment). Computationally, it's easier to just hard-code them and grab the prefix of the list needed to produce the output.

Comment: And additionally for the twenty exceptions (anoumlus electrons) it would be a good idea to add an if statment stating them.

Comment: @chepner thank you for your help your answer is good, I'm going to try to improve it

Comment: @Hilea can you tell me more about those exceptions ?